# UITextView in custom inputaccessoryView not resigning first responder status

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a chat application that implements a floating text input field (similar to the iOS Messages app) as the `inputAccessoryView` of my `ChatViewController` (see [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html)).

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController {

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
       return chatInputView
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
    ...
```

My `ChatViewController` has a `ChatTableViewController` child view controller, which has cells containing `UITextField`s whose text content is editable. The issue I'm running into is that when the user taps on a cell's `UITextField`, the `inputAccessoryView`'s `UITextView` refuses to resign first responder status, which prevents the content in the `UITableViewCell` from being edited. The following warning is logged in the console:

```
 First responder warning: '<UITextView: 0x7fc041041c00; 
 frame = ...' rejected resignFirstResponder when being removed from hierarchy
```

I've tried calling `resignFirstResponder` and `endEditing` on the `UIInputView` and `UITextView` directly with no success. I don't want the `ChatViewController` to resign first responder status as that would cause the `inputAccessoryView` to disappear.

Edit: I also receive the warning when dismissing the keyboard interactively (instead of tapping on the `UITableViewCell`'s `UITextField`.

Comment: try [self.view endEditing:YES] or [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];

Comment: can you upload the relevant classes on github or maybe mail it over?

Comment: I've uploaded gists of the relevant files here (with irrelevant code removed for brevity's sake): https://gist.github.com/blau2/d4e49cbc3c59b4058e410bdf72a7007d

Comment: @blau Any progress on this?

Comment: @AaronBratcher negative. Unfortunately I've had to table this for the time-being to deal with other higher priority issues.

Comment: @blau I'm facing same issue any solution for this?

Comment: @Yuvrajsinh unfortunately not. Our design spec changed so I no longer needed to implement this as an inputAccessoryView.  Would be nice to find a solution for this but I haven't had the opportunity to dig any further.

Comment: I've meet similar situation. In my case, when a `WKWebView` from my app's main window try to acquire first responder, UIKit grant it without asking the original first responder on an input accessory view on another `UIWindow`: UIKit does not call the `resignFirstResponder` for the original first responder, instead it throwing a `rejected resignFirstResponder when being removed from hierarchy` warning.

Comment: @Yuvrajsinh did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Edan did anyone find a solution for this?

Comment: I've found that this issue even happens in Apple's Messages app.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check the following:

#### If `UITextView` is removed from super view:

- Is the `UITextView` being removed from the view hierarchy ?
- If so could you `resignFirstResponder` before removing it from the super view.

#### If `UITextView` subclass is being used:

- Are you using a subclass of `UITextView`, if so have you implemented `canResignFirstResponder` to return `false`.
- Could you try returning `true` instead.

Comment: I'm not removing the `UITextView` from its superview. The `UITextView`'s superview remains as the custom `UIInputView` subclass after the first responder changes. I'm also just using a plain old `UITextView` (not a subclass).

Comment: May be the `superView` is available, but superView's `superView` might be `nil`. Could you keep checking the `superView` recursively until you reach the window. `UITextView` needs to be in the hierarchy to be able to dismiss the keyboard

Comment: I've done as you suggested and the hierarchy is as follows: `UITextView` - `ChatInputView` - `UIInputSetHostView` - `UIInputSetContainerView` - `UITextEffectsWindow`. As you suggest the `UITextView` isn't part of the app's view hierarchy since I can't recursively reach the window. 

I am unsure as to why this is happening. I don't believe I have to manually add it to the view hierarchy, as all the documentation I've read indicates that all that needs to be done is to override the `inputAccessoryView` property in my view controller and it should be taken care of.

Comment: What is `UITextEffectsWindow` ? I would imagine normally you would add `subViews` directly / indirectly to `UIViewController.view`. Try to keep it simple, try it on a new project.

Answer (score 1):

This warning is also shown when using the iOS message app and whatsApp. There is no known way to get rid of that. It has no negative impact, I believe we should just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. override canBecomeFirstResponder to your inputAccessoryView and that UITextField on inputAccessoryView
2. when user pressed hide keyboard or return, set canBecomeFirstResponder to false
3. remove inputAccessoryView from its superView

still have warning message when press hide keyboard, but works well for me.